# Grid items overlapping when resizing browser with columns set to 1fr

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm designing my website with CSS grid and I am facing a real issue when defining my grid with `1fr`.

Everything looks fine in large browser window, but the items start to overlap as the browser window gets quite small.

Has anyone experienced that? And if so, has anyone a solution?

my html

```
<div id="box-0"></div>
<div class="box-1">TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</div>
<div class="box-2">TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</div>
<div class="box-3">TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</div>
<div class="box-4">TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</div>
<div class="box-5">TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</div>
<div class="box-6">TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</div>
<div class="box-7">TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</div>
<div class="box-8">TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</div>
```

my css

```
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

#box-0 {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1/10;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-1 {
    grid-row: 2/span 2;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-2 {
    grid-row: 4/span 2;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-3 {
    grid-row: 2/span 1;
    grid-column: 2/10;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-4 {
    grid-row: 3/span 3;
    grid-column: 2/8;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-5 {
    grid-row: 3/span 3;
    grid-column: 8/10;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-6 {
    grid-row: 6/span 2;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-7 {
    grid-row: 6/span 2;
    grid-column: 4/7;
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-8 {
    grid-row: 6/span 2;
    grid-column: 7/10;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` or `overflow: hidden` to you grid items. https://jsfiddle.net/6c15uzka/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Michael-B! I was hoping I was in fact coding it wrong. It looks like it's not the case, alas...The `overflow: hidden` is not the property I'm looking for since I want the content to remain visible. `Min-width` is a property I'd already tried. It does the trick. I was just hoping I'd get by with the columns / raws sizes defined as 1 fr only, and no extra CSS...

Comment: Well, see the dupe for the reason for the extra CSS. You need to override a default setting. But it's only one short line of code.